# Create a list of strings with consecutive numbers appended

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure there must e an easy way to do this: I want to create a list which will eventually become column names for a DataFrame. There will be 13 columns, each representing a period in time, called "Period n", where n is the period number. I think there's probably a way to build this list via loop, but I will show what I tried to do:

```
col_no = list(range(1,14))
col_name = ['Period' for n in range (1,14)]
col_list = col_name + col_no

print(col_list)

['Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 'Period',
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13]
```

Then I tried:

```
col_list = list(zip(col_name + col_no))
print(col_list)

[('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 ('Period',),
 (1,),
 (2,),
 (3,),
 (4,),
 (5,),
 (6,),
 (7,),
 (8,),
 (9,),
 (10,),
 (11,),
 (12,),
 (13,)]
```

Basically, I just wanted an easily generated list that reads "Period 1", "Period 2", etc. I'm pretty new to Python, and pretty stumped.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can concatenate them (the number and the word Period) together while the loop iterates.

## Python 3.6+

```
print([f'Period {i}' for i in range(1, 14)])
```

## Python 2.7+

```
print(['Period {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 14)])
```

Comment: This is nice, might want a note that this is specific to Python 3.6+

Answer (score 7):

Pandas has convenient methods [**`pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) that do this for you.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(1, list('abc'), range(1, 5))
df

   1  2  3  4
a  1  1  1  1
b  1  1  1  1
c  1  1  1  1
```

---

```
df.add_prefix('Period_')

   Period_1  Period_2  Period_3  Period_4
a         1         1         1         1
b         1         1         1         1
c         1         1         1         1
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
['Period ' + str(n) for n in range(14)]
```

Comment: This is 100% the best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

You were on the right path in your last attempt:

```
zip(col_name + col_no)
```

The big problem is that `+` there. You concatenate the two lists together into one big list, and then try to zip that. What you wanted to do was zip the two lists:

```
zip(col_name, col_no)
```

… and then add the resulting pairs.

This means using a loop—whether a for statement, a list comprehension, the implicit loop inside `map`, ….

Also, you can’t just add a string and a number; you need to convert the number to a string first:

```
name + str(no)
```

… or use string formatting:

```
f"{name}{no}”
```

So, putting it all together:

```
[name + str(no) for name, no in zip(col_name, col_no)]
```

There are other ways to solve this (you don’t really need that list of a bunch of copies of the same name, for example), but this shows how to get there from where you were heading.

Answer (score 1):

You were appending a list of numbers to a list of `Period`s. To achieve what you want, you'd have needed to loop through the list of `Period`s and concatenate them with numbers 1 to 13. However a simpler solution exists so you can try this instead.

```
col_list = ['Period ' + str(n) for n in range(14)]
print col_list
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is the way to go:

```
solution = (['Period %i' %i for i in range(1, 14)])
```